# Placing a css button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a CSS button top right of the browser - how can I get it top right?! I've tried padding, top and so on

CSS looks like:

```
 #logoutbutton {
                        text-align: right;
                        position: relative;
                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tu5gv8j0/ - what the log out button looks like in relation to the other buttons

CSS of the other buttons:

```
.wrap {
            position: relative;
            }

            img {
                position: absolute;
            }

            h1 {
                color:red;
                font-family:Trebuchet MS;
                font-size:250%;
                text-align:center;
            }   

            .btn {
                background: #3498db;
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
                font-family: Arial;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 25px;
                padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .btn:hover {
                background: #3cb0fd;
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #mainbuttons {
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                top: 200px;
            }



            .btn:first-child, .btn:nth-child(2)  {
                margin-right: 30px;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

[JS Fiddle - absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/tu5gv8j0/1/)

```
#logoutbutton {
                right: 0;               
                top: 0;
                position: absolute;

}
```

or

[JS Fiddle - fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/tu5gv8j0/3/)

```
#logoutbutton {
                right: 0;               
                top: 0;
                position: fixed;

}
```

Documentation on the "position" property: [CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: thanks, difference between absolute and fixed? to move the button down from the top should i use padding? thnx

Comment: Fixed position is relative to the window, while absolute is relative to it's parent. Meaning, if you scroll with fixed position, it will stay in your view.  Top move it down, use `top: #px;`

Comment: @dwreck08 small correction: absolute position is relative to its first parent that has its position set to anything other than `static`

Comment: Strictly speaking, an element with `position: fixed` is positioned in relation to the upper-left corner of the user-agent's view-port, whereas the window itself encompasses the browser's chrome and controls (minimal though that is, these days). I don't know how much the distinction matters, though, in practice.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
#logoutbutton {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

is this what you tried to achieve?

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
}
h1 {
    color:red;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:250%;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn {
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #3cb0fd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainbuttons {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}
#logoutbutton {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.btn:first-child, .btn:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<title>Sports day</title>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Highdown logo" />
         <h1>Sports day</h1> 
    </div>
    <div id="mainbuttons">
        <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/sportsday/entryformsuccess.php'">Entry forms</button>
        <button class="btn">Scoresheets</button>
        <button class="btn">Results</button>
    </div>
    <div id="logoutbutton">
        <button class="btn">Logout</button>
        <div>
```

Comment: @Ezzat with all due respect to css units, 0 is 0. whatever the unit.

Answer (score 1):

`#logoutbutton {position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}`

Using absolute positioning pulls the button outside of the normal flow, and positions it in relation to the closest containing block, in this case the browser window.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/roachdesign/dyvduehr/
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#logoutbutton {

                    position: absolute;
                    top:0px; 
                    right:0px;
                }
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and built for you.  Apply position fixed so it will never moved from that top right position.  Meaning, it will float continually on the page in that position.  Then you just need to specify the position / margins.  In this case, you want it 0px from the top and 0px from the right.  Adjust accordingly if you want padding / margins etc.

```
<style>
#button{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
</style>


<div id="button">button</div>
```